# Convolution of two Gaussians or two sinc functions using direct integration

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, convolution

I tried to solve the following to problems from Gaskil's book Linear Systems, Fourier Transforms, and Optics. But I'm struggling to get the right results. My experience with calculating convolutions is very limited. I wanted to see how this could be done using direct integration, the filter theorem makes the task trivial.

#### (a.)

$GAUS\left[\frac{x}{3}\right]\ast GAUS\left[\frac{x}{4}\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\pi\left(\frac{\alpha}{3}\right)^2}e^{-\pi\left(\frac{x-\alpha}{4}\right)^2}\mathrm{d}\alpha$

#### (b.)

$SINC\left[3x\right]\ast SINC\left[2x\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin[3\pi\alpha]}{3\pi\alpha}\right)\left(\frac{\sin[2\pi(x-\alpha)]}{2\pi(x-\alpha)}\right)\mathrm{d}\alpha$

Comment: The convolution of two Gaussians is routine; I don't know about the other one.

Comment: The direct \sinc convolution is ugly because of the $\alpha^2$ in the denominator - there's likely no elementary anti-derivative. Have you tried converting it to a complex integral?

Comment: Oh Sorry I made a mistake with the Sinc equation. It should be x-\alpha on the bottom

Comment: No, I didn't convert to complex integral I could give that a try. my integration skills are a bit rusty though